# What is the HTML code in this Code Pen with `%button`?

Tags: html, codepen

The HTML looks like:

```
%button.darkmode dark mode
%button.refresh regenerate
#wrap
 -10.times do
  .row
   -5.times do
    .cell
```

https://codepen.io/cobra_winfrey/pen/ZEYzMBj

What is the markup language utilized?

Comment: [Haml](http://haml.info/) (look next to html - it says what extra languages it is using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%button.darkmode dark mode` will generate `<button class="darkmode">dark mode</button>`

`%button.refresh regenerate` will generate `<button class="refresh">regenerate</button>`

> [Haml (HTML Abstraction Markup Language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml) is a templating system that is designed to avoid writing inline code in a web document and make the HTML cleaner. Haml gives the flexibility to have some dynamic content in HTML. Similar to other web languages like PHP, ASP, JSP and template systems like eRuby, Haml also embeds some code that gets executed during runtime and generates HTML code in order to provide some dynamic content. In order to run Haml code, files need to have .haml extension. These files are similar to .erb or eRuby files which also help to embed Ruby code while developing a web application.